# Accessing data in `RetrieveMultiple`

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I'm fetching `Contact`and `Account` entities and I wish to access the name of the contact and the name of the primary contact. While the first one is accessed very easily by

```
EntityCollection result = proxy.RetrieveMultiple(...);
Entity entity = result.Entities[0].Attributes["fullname"];
```

the other seems to fight me throwing an exception. As far I can see, it depends on the fetch XML that has attributes for the name directly in `<entity>` in the former case and under `<entity><link-entity>` in the latter.

How can I access the field `fullname` that is a linked entity?

---

Fetch XML for contacts:

```
<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true'>
  <entity name='contact'>
    <attribute name='fullname' />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Fetch XML for accounts' primary contacts:

```
<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true'>
  <entity name='account'>
    <attribute name='accountid'/>
    <link-entity name='listmember' from='entityid' to='accountid' visible='false' intersect='true'>
      <link-entity name='list' from='listid' to='listid' alias='ab'>
      </link-entity>
    </link-entity>
    <link-entity name='contact' from='contactid' to='primarycontactid' visible='false' link-type='outer' alias='...'>
      <attribute name='fullname'/>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a response to the original question, the answer from GCTANM and comments (my thoughts are too long for the comments).

There appears to be a couple of confusions here I would like to clear up.

**GCTANM:**

> RetrieveMultiple can only use LinkEntities for selection purposes, it
> cannot return attributes for entities other than the primary entity of
> the query.
>
> ...
>
> for any other attributes of
> those contact records, you'd have to take each contact's ID and do one
> of those Retrieve calls mentioned in my comment.

These statements are not correct, you can return attributes of all the linked entities as well. There is an example of this on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328149.aspx).

**Chamster**

> By the sound of its name, Fetch will only return a single result,
> won't it?

FetchXml returns a single result set, but that result set can contain the details of many records.

> Somehow, I'd prefer to work with XML than entities

If you really (really really) wanted to do that you could use the Crm 4 Web Services, the RetrieveMultiple still returns an Xml result set.

**To answer the original question.**

So the reason your probably struggling to get back your attribute it because the EntityCollection that is returned has a slightly peculiar behaviour which was introduced in Crm 2011.

In short, Crm 4 FetchXml queries would return an Xml result you had to parse, in 2011 to help you out Microsoft parse the result into an EntityCollection. This results in some attributes having quite unexpected names.

So taking the example of you contact above, you would have to access the fullname attribute using something like this: `contact1.fullname`, the contact is the link, the number is representative of the number of links, and fullname is the attribute.

I can't remember the exact format and I'm struggling to find a decent example. I would suggest setting a breakpoint after your query and inspecting the results, I'm certain you will find the data but with names like above.

If I can find a decent example (or create one tommorrow) I'll update my post.

Comment: I'll dive into the watch-utility tomorrow. I've been looking at the member fields in the returned entities but I don't recall anything like what you're describing. I hope I just missed that due to full scale confusion.   :)

Comment: Okay, I dove in, like promised. Then I jumped right back up and ran away screaming and crying. What on Earth is **that**?! You said "*something like `contact1.fullname`*". I don't think I quite understood the like-art, haha. On my machine it says: `a_410707b195544cd984376608b1802904.fullname`. Was that MS helping me?   :D     Is there a neat method to get the value of the atrocity or do I need to look for "*fullname*" using `EndsWith` in the `Keys`? That doesn't appear to me fully pro...

Comment: Ha, I was expecting that, it might be because you set an alias on the link-entity. I've seen far more sensible names, I'll get an example together later on.

Comment: Just got it. One need only to set alias parameter **inside** the attribute in the fetchXML! Beautiful! Scratch the hate-part... :)

Comment: Typo in previous comment should read "wasnt expecting that". :). Glad its working.

Comment: As a side, you dont actually need to set an alias at all.

Comment: But if I don't set `alias` I get this very "helpful" naming convention shoved up my face. I prefer my contacts' name be referred to as `name` or `fullname` instead av `&%¤!#%%&%¤!&%¤!.fullname`. Much less scary. Perhaps you ment something else, though?

Comment: O I thought it would be a nice name, something like entityname.attributename, I'll have to investigate later.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean. And I agree. No point setting an alias if the name is pronouncable. But in this case... Well, I just learned the usage of aliases, haha! Thanks.

Comment: Crm4 FetchXml is ***deprecated*** in _CRM 2016_. Do you prefer work XML (results, not FetchXml as input)  that Entities in CRM 2016? Really ?

Comment: @Kiquenet, this question is 4 years old!

Answer (score 0):

`RetrieveMultiple` can only use LinkEntities for selection purposes, it cannot return attributes for entities other than the primary entity of the query.

However, when you include the `primarycontactid` attribute in the `ColumnSet` for the account query, that will be an `EntityReference` whose `Name` property contains the `fullname` of the contact. 
That's coincidental though, as the `fullname` attribute is the "primary name" attribute of the `contact` entity, and that's what's used in `EntityReference` objects.

Elaborating, as you requested:

`RetrieveMultiple` takes a `QueryBase` object (most commonly a `QueryExpression`), which has a property called `ColumnSet` to define which attributes to return (which can make a difference in performance, especially for entities with many fields).

In your case, it might be set up like this:

```
QueryExpression qryAccounts = new QueryExpression("account")
{
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("accountid", "name", "primarycontactid")
};

qryAccounts.Criteria.AddCondition("primarycontactid", ConditionOperator.NotNull);

qryAccounts.AddLink("list", "accountid", "entityid");


EntityCollection collAccounts = svcOrganization.RetrieveMultiple(qryAccounts);
```

Now, if any of the records returned in `collAccounts.Entities` has a primary contact (in this case, they all will, because that was one of our conditions, aka `select` clauses), its `Attributes` collection will include an item keyed `primarycontactid`, and the value will be of type `EntityReference`.

This has the properties `Id`, `LogicalName` (this being the name of the referenced entity, in this case "contact") and `Name`, which is the value of the entity's primary name attribute; for `contact`, that is `fullname` (for `account` it's `name`, and so on - always the name that you see in grids or lookups for the respective entity).

But as I said, that is a coincidence, and for any other attributes of those contact records, you'd have to take each contact's ID and do one of those `Retrieve` calls mentioned in my comment.

A `Fetch` using actual FetchXML (with the result also being XML) *can* directly return attributes of linked records, as far as I remember.

Comment: Hmm... By the sound of its name, `Fetch` will only return a single result, won't it? If so, how can I fetch a list of entities? If not, why in God's name is it called `RetrieveMultiple` (emphasis on **multiple**)?!

Comment: Uhmmm... The middle paragraph, starting with "*however*" I don't understand at all. Could you elaborate, please, keeping in mind that my experience with CRM Dynamics is as vast as the month of September (this year).

Comment: `RetrieveMultiple` is named such because it can retrieve *multiple* records that fit the (arbitrary) query criteria, as opposed to `Retrieve` that can get a single record based on its ID (which has to be known). `Fetch` is a different method that's only really important from JavaScript nowadays; it takes the above actual FetchXML and returns the result in XML form as well instead of an EntityCollection. That result XML can also contain attributes of linked records, as mentioned above.

Comment: That was one **darn good** answer... I hear that `Fetch` is kind of deprecated-ish and one should rely on `RetrieveMultiple` whenever possible? Somehow, I'd prefer to work with XML than entities, especially if the data returned **always** can be fetched that way.'

Comment: Well, I guess you could; maybe even wrapping the result XML handling in your own version of an `EntityCollection` or the like. But honestly, in five years I never seriously considered that; it's too rarely that you'd ever need the added flexibility, and the convenience of the Query/Entity classes outweighs that, especially if you write a lot of this stuff. Except for a few occasions (I can think of two in all those years), we don't use fetches from .NET code, and even in JavaScript where they're still the way to go, we use third party libraries to transform the fetch result to objects.

Comment: I down voted this one because I doesnt appear to be accurate please see my answer below.

Comment: I still like your answer but @JamesWood has a valid point. I'd give you both a green check but I can't and if I'll be explaining the stuff to a moron (e.g. myself, after 16 hours of typing) his explanation is more idiot-proof.